# Get the text box value and display it into the h3 element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tried to get the text box value and display into the h3 element in above the textbox field

**Here is my HTML Code :**

```
 <div class="clonedInput" id="add_attribute" style="display: block;">
    <div id="add_attributes">
      <div id="accordion1">
        <h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong class="attribute_name">**Here Text box value should be displayed**</strong> </h3>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="attribute_data" class="">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="attribute_name"><label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="attribute_name" class="attribute_name" name="attribute_names[]">
              </td>
              <td rowspan="3"><label>Value(s):</label>
                <textarea name="attribute_values[]" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text, or some attributes"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clonedInput" id="add_attribute_2" style="display: block;">
    <div id="add_attributes" class="woocommerce_attribute wc-metabox ">
      <div id="accordion1">
        <h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong class="attribute_name"></strong> </h3>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="attribute_data" class="">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="attribute_name"><label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="attribute_name" class="attribute_name" name="attribute_names[]">
              </td>
              <td rowspan="3"><label>Value(s):</label>
                <textarea name="attribute_values[]" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text, or some attributes"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clonedInput" id="add_attribute_3" style="display: block;">
    <div id="add_attributes" class="woocommerce_attribute wc-metabox ">
      <div id="accordion1">
        <h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong class="attribute_name"></strong> </h3>
          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="attribute_data" class="">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="attribute_name"><label>Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="attribute_name" class="attribute_name" name="attribute_names[]">
              </td>
              <td rowspan="3"><label>Value(s):</label>
                <textarea name="attribute_values[]" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text, or some attributes"></textarea>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to get the input field value `<input type="text" id="attribute_name" class="attribute_name" name="attribute_names[]">` and display the value into the "

```
<h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong class="attribute_name">"**Here the text box value"</strong> </h3>
```

" on blur function and this was dynamic text box

**My Jquery :**

```
$( "input" ).blur(function() {
            var string = $(this).val();
            $(this).parent().append(string);
        });
```

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Do you want to display textbox value in place of "**Here the text box value" right?

Answer (score 1):

I added an id attribute to the h3 where you want to display it and use that as reference on the blur event callback: **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TK2Th/3/)**

**HTML**

```
<strong class="attribute_name" id="output">**Here Text box value should be displayed**</strong> </h3>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input").blur(function () {
    var string = $(this).val();
    $('#output').html(string);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place text box value in place of `**Here Text box value should be displayed**`, please try this:

```
$( "input" ).blur(function() {
    var string = $(this).val();
    $(".attribute_name").text(string);
});
```

Comment: This will add the value to all the headers on the page whereas OP only wanted to update the related `h3`.

Answer (score 0):

See a working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/wPCZ5/

You need to do this in your handler:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('h3 > strong').html(string);
```

for all text boxes to work. The `closest()` call looks up the DOM hierarchy and returns the first matching element. In  your case, it is the accordion div. The `find()` call then looks down the DOM hierarchy for the matching element. Finally `html()` replaces the current HTML within the element with the supplied string. Your original call to `append()` would add the string to whatever is already present.

Comment: Yep, it'd. Please accept the answer so that it's removed from the question stream.

Comment: Also as an aside, I think the effect will look nice if you updated the header as the user typed into the text box.

Answer (score 0):

There's a working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/u63CU/ but I think you should not reuse class and ID names like you have. It can lead to many undesired results, as jquery selects by id or class name.

```
<div class="clonedInput" id="add_attribute" style="display: block;">
    <div id="add_attributes">
      <div id="accordion1">
        <h3>
          <input type="button" value="Remove" class="btnDel remove_row button" name="btnDelete1">
          <strong id="text-value" class="attribute_name">**Here Text box value should be     displayed**</strong> </h3>
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="attribute_data" class="">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="attribute_name"><label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="attribute_name" class="attribute_name" name="attribute_names[]">
          </td>
          <td rowspan="3"><label>Value(s):</label>
            <textarea name="attribute_values[]" cols="5" rows="5" placeholder="Enter some text, or some attributes"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
$( "#attribute_name" ).blur(function() {
    var string = $(this).val();
    $('#text-value').text(string);
});
```

Comment: Pretty much, but I believe if you use the .html it will replace the entire element, whereas the .text will replace what's inside the element. A matter of taste I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    $( "input" ).blur(function() {
           $(this).closest('strong.attribute_name').text(this.value);
       });
```